# No Office 365 Exchange app in Azure AD

Tags: office365, office365api

I used to create my App for using Outlook API for Office 365 via Azure AD.

I go to Azure AD and I create an app, I configure it adding the Office 365 Exchange Online, and I'm good to go.

Today, I create a new account on Azure AD, and in my list of available apps, 
Exchange Online has disappeared :/

I have only the choice between:

1. Window Azure Service Management API
2. Microsoft Graph (not usable since its still not stable)
3. Office 365 management api

Where are all the other options I used to have, Office, SharePoint, etc...

Can anyone explain me if there is any bug on Azure AD.

The same happen when registering a new account on Office 365, account created, but all apps (Word, PowerPoint, OneNote, OneDrive etc...) I usually have are missing.

Thanks for you support.

Answer (score 1):

All the options are now under Microsoft Graph, which is now generally available and should be stable. You can read more at https://graph.microsoft.io.

From http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/11/19/introducing-the-microsoft-graph-the-azure-ad-graphapi-goes-big-time.aspx and https://blogs.office.com/2015/11/18/today-at-connect-introducing-the-microsoft-graph/:

> [...] at the Connect() conference in New York, the Office Extensibility and Azure Active Directory teams announced the General Availability (GA) of the Microsoft Graph (formerly "Office 365 unified API" as previewed at //build earlier this year) [...]

Comment: Graph is stable ?? You mean the unified API is stable, i was on the blog today and its still shown as preview, having this api stable would make my xmas, but i stop believing in santa claus long time ago, can you confirm?

Comment: Can you share the blog post you're referring to? Microsoft Graph has reached v1.0, which is stable.